# How can I store / cache values from methods in a class for later use in other methods of the same class?

Tags: python, oop, caching, machine-learning

I am writing a linear regression class which fits a model to some data, similar to the [scikit-learn implementation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html).

Once the model is fit, I want to be able to call a `predict()` method **without** having to pass the trained model weights as a parameter to the method. What I have so far is below

```
class LinReg:
    """ Fit a linear model to data"""
    def __init__(self):
        ....

    def fit(self, x, y):
        """Fit a model to data x with targets y"""
        ...
        # model weights w are calculated here
        return w

    def predict(self, x, w):
        """Predict the target variable of the data x using trained weights w"""
        ...
        # predicted y values, y_pred, are calulated here
        return y_pred
```

The trained weights `w` are returned from `fit()` so the user can store these as a variable to later pass to the `predict()` method.

```
lm = LinReg()
w = lm.fit(x,y)
y_pred = lm.predict(x_new, w) # don't want to pass w here
```

However, I do not want to return `w` from `fit()`; I want to somehow store `w` once it is calculated in `fit()` so that the user does not have to concern themselves with the weights, but also such that the weights can be easily used in the `predict()` method.

How do I do this? Is there a pythonic or standard OO way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would store it as an instance-level property:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.w = None  # define the prop here...
    ....

def fit(self, x, y):
    """Fit a model to data x with targets y"""
    ...
    # model weights w are calculated here
    self.w = your_computed_value

def predict(self, x):
    """Predict the target variable of the data x using trained weights w"""
    ...
    # predicted y values, y_pred, are calulated here
    do_something_here(self.w)
    return y_pred
```